# Combine fixed sidebar and fluid content with Push-Pull-Classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

---

**In a Nutshell:**
This is what i want to achieve:  https://jsfiddle.net/Pintolus/faz88ayh/33 (you have to resize the result window to see the effect) but the #Content Div should fill out the rest of the screen-space next to the #Sidebar.
The Sidebar should still move UNDER the #Content on small screens.

---

This is what i want to achieve:
There should be 3 divs:

- #Sidebar, which is on the left side and has a fixed width
- #Content, which is on the right side and has a fluid width
- #Footer, which is on the bottom of the page and is full width

That is not a big deal, but i want the #Sidebar to move under the #Content on small screens. This alone is also not a big deal and can be achieved by using Bootstraps Push- and Pull-Classes.

The problem is, that i have no idea how to combine both issues.
I want the sidebar to be fixed width (until it moves down) **AND** to move under the content-div.

This is the code for the left sidebar moving under the #Content:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3" id="content"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9" id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (Just for demo)

```
 #sidebar {background: #CCC; height: 150px;}
 #content {background: #111; height: 100px;}
 #footer {background: #F00; height: 100px;}
```

**[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/28/)** (You have to resize the results window).
Now i want the Sidebar in this fiddle to be fixed width (for example 100px).

Please help, this drives me crazy.

PS: `position: absolute` for the sidebar is no solution, because it will overlap the footer (due to different height).

Comment: I updated your fiddle with the required container element to eliminate the horizontal body scroll. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: You can do this with media queries: http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your push/pull works, bu I assume it's classes that appear on both your divs.

I wonder whether it would be easier to do that with media queries.

Anyway, here's a way to do it (sorry, my knowledge of bootstrap is close to nil, so I went for a very simplified piece of code):

http://jsfiddle.net/txLaukqm/1/

HTML :

```
<div id="sidebar"></div
><div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-size: 0; /* to fight the space before the footer due to inline-block */
}
body * {
    font-size: 1rem; /* to reset the font-size */
}
#sidebar {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CCC;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#sidebar.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #111;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    overflow: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#content.full-width {
    width: 100%;    
}
#footer {
    background: #F00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it doesnt work well with the bootstrap push and pull classes applied.

Your solution works well until i try to move the sidebar under the content on small screen sizes. This is because the Sidebar is the first element mentioned in the HTML Code, so it will always stay on the top.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pintolus/txLaukqm/2/

Comment: if, using those push/pull classes, you change the widths of the sidebar and the content like I did in "#sidebar.hidden" and "#content.full-width", I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: The Sidebar simply disappears in your fiddle.

Comment: Ah, ok, I finally got what you're asking. Sorry :)

Comment: This is very near to what i want to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Pintolus/faz88ayh/33/ Now the Content Div should fill out the rest of the screen-space next to the Sidebar and it would be perfect.

Comment: this is excalty what i wanted to achieve, but i try to avoid the css "calc" because its not well supported on many browsers.

Comment: It is supported on IE9+ and recent versions of android browser and iOS Safari. If people use older browsers than that, it's kind of their own fault, don't you think? http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: We actually use it at work for professional SaaS applications. We finally decided to say f**k to IE8.

Comment: I dont care about IE8 and below, but android only supports it since Version 4.4 and its only partial support :(

Comment: Anyway, if you really don't want to use calc, you can achieve the same thing with additional divs, padding, border-box and absolute positionning. Here's an example of how to do it: http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/yyEqOx.

Comment: It's way less elegant though... as for Android support, look at the "browser usage" in caniuse for the older versions. It's close to nonexistant.

Comment: You are using position: absolute in that example. I cant use position absolute for the Sidebar or Content because they are different (and variable due to dynamic content) height and will overlap the footer. I would give you many thumbs up but i cant since i have not enough reputation. Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: It shouldn't matter. You should be able to use absolute positioning anyway. In my last fiddle (jsfiddle.net/umzrgvd4/2), I used absolute positioning, and the sidebar is not on the footer.

Comment: (less elegant, isn't it? ;) )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umzrgvd4/4/ it doesnt seem to work properly when the Sidebar and the Content have different or variable heights. If the Footer would position at the bottom of the highest element, it would be perfect!

Comment: So in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umzrgvd4/5/ the footer should begin at the bottom of the sidebar

Comment: Yeah, but now its scrollable if its higher than the content div. Maybe it is just impossible to do without calc or absolute positioning, but both of them are non-perfect solutions. So i should consider to let the sidebar stay fluid : /. This problem did cost me an entire day and also plenty of your time. Thank you so much.

Comment: If what you need is the whole page (including the footer) to be vertically scrollable when the sidebar is higher than the content div... then yes I think you're gonna need calc(). If what you need if the sidebar and the content to be vertically scrollable together (at the same time), but the footer to always stay visible, I think it is doable without calc().

Comment: I just realised, that it is regardless of whether Android does support calc() or not, because on small displays only divs are displayed, which do not use calc() parameters : )
http://jsfiddle.net/faz88ayh/34/

Comment: You're welcome. I'm still a little confused about what you wanted to achieve, but I'm glad you achieved it ;)